# Fetching json data from password protected url using php and curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to fetch a json string from a password protected url.

I think my code should work but when I open my script in the browser I just have a blank page.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$url = 'https://api.domain.com?api=latest&format=json';

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($data);

?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is curl_exec returning false? If it is false check if curl_errno($ch) and curl_error($ch) are set.

Comment: Have you try printing out $result before json_decode? does result have anything. That may be a better indication if curl parameters are setup correctly vs something else is wrong. Also print out $info to see what curl has return as a message.

Comment: Hi @Churk, just printed out `$info` and everything except url, content_type, namelookup_time and connect_time are set to 0. Will try your suggesting just now @Tjkoopa. Also, printing `$result` doesn't change it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
```

Comment: came back to post that `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` fixed it, wish I'd seen your post earlier! Thanks